# I create a method in class(creating dynamic label) , which context should I use for ....Contors.Add(label)?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, class, methods

ı want to create dynamic label in form1 design, when ı start the code. but ı dont know which context should ı use ? which context should ı use in line 59-60-61-62 instead of f1?(windows form app)

[my code's class photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8GIa.png)

[my code's form1 photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbHiB.png)

Comment: In the form constructor, after calling `InitializeComponent();`. Do not post code as image. Insert it as text into your question.

Comment: why ? is there any rule like that ? ı am beginner in this website.

Comment: Because you say "when I start code". But of course, you can set it in a button click, for example. It depends when you want to add the dynamic controls.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes ı edited my question, ı posted as a image. can you help me :)

Comment: What is the problem with the current code? Can't you just add the controls in the designer and make them public, so that you can just the `Text` property from outside? `f1.lblSaat.Text = saat;`. Or you can pass these parameters in the Form1 constructor and move all this code to there. `Form1 f1 = new Form1(saat,gosterlilecekResimYolu, ad, tur);`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I have to create in class, this is my homework. I have to create label in class then show in form1. can ı do that ?

Comment: Please don't include code as picture. Prefer copy/paste and format it (with markdown style)